# Obtener informacion de una boleta segun el usuario

Tags: php, sql

```
[![<?php

require ('conn.php');
session_start();

$dni=$_POST['dni_usuario'];
$pass=$_POST['contraseña_usu'];
$nivel=$_POST['nivel'];

$sqlU = "SELECT * FROM usuario  WHERE dni_usuario='".$dni."' AND contraseña_usu='".$pass."' AND nivel= '".$nivel."'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sqlU);
$filas=$result->num_rows;
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ($filas==0 ) {    

    echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Error Cargo');
    window.location= '../usuario.html'
    </script>";

}else{  
    $nivel = $row['nivel']; 

    switch ($nivel) {    
       case 0: 
           echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Acceso Correcto');
            window.location= '../tabla_recibo.php'
            </script>";
       break;
    
      case 1:
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Acceso Correcto');
          window.location= '../tabla_recibo.php?'
          </script>";
      break;
    
      default:
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Error');
           window.location= '../usuario.html'
          </script>";
      break;
        }
}
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAE4z.png)][1][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas tardes necesito ayuda estoy empezando en esto de la programacion, estoy haciendo un proyecto donde el cliente tiene una interfaz a la cual es una tabla donde le salen sus recibos, y lo que necesito es que le carguen sus recibos que tenga cada cliente que inicia, osea que carguen los recibos en la tabla de acuerdo al usuario que se logee, nose si me dejo entender, alguien si me pudiera dar una manito gracias..!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
            <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered" 
                   style="width:100%">
                      <thead>
                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                          <th>ESTADO</th>
                          <th>NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS</th>
                          <th>MES FACTURADO</th>
                          <th>PLAN</th>
                          <th>TOTAL</th>
                          <th>ACCIONES</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <?php
                $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario INNER JOIN recibo ON usuario.dni_usuario = recibo.usuario_id_usuario";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);
                while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                  echo "<tbody  style='text-align: center;'>";
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>" . $columna['Estado'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $columna['Nombres'] ." ". $columna['Apellidos'] ."</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $columna['Fech_Fact'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $columna['Servicio'] . "</td>"; 
                  echo "<td>" . $columna['Total'] . "</td>"; 
                  echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' 
                  data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg'>revisar recibo</button> </td>";                   
                            
                                       
                  echo "</tr>";
                  echo "</tbody>";
                }
                  ?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110560/discussion-on-question-by-alex-lh-obtener-informacion-de-una-boleta-segun-el-usu).

Answer (score 0):

Según el modelo entidad relación que adjuntas, tu tabla `recibo` tiene la clave foránea `usuario_id_usuario` por lo que si quieres obtener todos los recibos de un determinado usuario la consulta que debes realizar es:

```sql
select * from recibo as r
inner join usuario as u
on r.usuario_id_usuario = u.dni_usuario
where usuario_id_usuario = id_usuario
```

Por ejemplo: el usuario con DNI 123456789A ha iniciado sesión en la plataforma, la consulta resultante sería:

```sql
select * from recibo as r
inner join usuario as u
on r.usuario_id_usuario = u.dni_usuario
where usuario_id_usuario = 123456789A
```

Comment: Pero a tu consulta le hace falta poder recuperar los datos de la persona como su nombre que si notas trata de imprimir en su tabla

Comment: Buena apreciación, ya he actualizado la consulta